# what could be another environment? AI learning

Tags: anaconda, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to set up my NVIDIA GPU CUDA development environment. I have Anaconda installed, when in console, I can see a (base) in front of my console.

I remember that I have another environment-like thing even before the (base), and it looks like:

`(env) (base) myname@DESKTOP-XDNA71A:~$`

I installed CUDA driver, toolkit in that environment, or something like an environment.

But when I typed

```
conda list environment
```

I can only see the base environment there.

How can I figure out what the environment-like thing could possible be?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: maybe it's python virtual environment, or another instalation of conda environment, open new console and post how prompt looks like, and post changes in ```.bash_rc```

Comment: thanks @quester!!! yes, it is the Python Virtual Environment~! thank you so much ~! you can make your comment an answer and I will be happy to accept it :)

Comment: happy to help...